# How to auto populate a field when a new record is created in MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a table that lists various components in a factory. When a component is added to the table there are certain columns that I have to manually type "Yes" or "No" (note: I want to keep this a text field and not a yes/no field). When I create a record I would like a filler in these columns such as "N/E" for "not evaluated" so I know to go back and analyze the component. Is there anyway that I can auto populate a field with just "N/E" when a new record is created?

Answer (score 3):

Open the table in design view, select each field and set the "Default Value".
This will set your "Default Value" for every new record but not for records which exist already in the table.